# Laravel Pluck - how to get more than one field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I show more than the first name? Select and pluck use key => value method (via id here), where do I write other columns I would like to bring into view ( such as last_name, paygrade, etc.)?
I would like to keep using the eloquent convention and show more info on the selected option.

**Controller**

`$users = User::select('id', 'first_name')->pluck('first_name', 'id');`

**Blade**
`{!! Form::select('worker_id',  $users, isset($users) ? $users : null, array('class' => 'form-control chosen-select', 'data-placeholder'=> 'Worker...', 'multiple' => 'multiple')) !!}`

Comment: Why do you think you need `pluck` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this:

```
$users = User::selectRaw('id, CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) as full_name')->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

or this:

```
$users = User::select('id', DB::raw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name")->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I was looking for, your code is not eloquent, please change it and I will vote it as answer.
`$users = User::selectRaw('id, CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) as full_name')->pluck('full_name', 'id');`

Comment: you can use **concat** just in raw like **DB::raw()** and rest code as **eloquent**

Comment: I did it and offer the two ways to wrote